# ScriptStore.ValidateKey is throwing error in 10.2

Tags: sitecore-forms

We are doing an upgradation from `SC9.2` to `SC10.2`. We are facing an issue in `Recaptcha.cshtml`. **ScriptStore.ValidateKey** is throwing error doing the compilation. Because `ScriptStore.ValidateKey` is not there in the Upgraded version of `Feature.FormExtension.DLL`. So anyone helps me out with how to validate the key in the file?

Attached the screenshot

[image]